# how to generate html elements without increasing page height

Tags: javascript, html, web, height

I'm working on a web page that has multiple pages to display.

```
<div class='tab'>
    <div class='page'>...</div>
    ...
    <div class='page'>...</div>
</div>
```

but the web page's height extends a long way beyond the length of 1 shown page.  I'm afraid that what is causing this is that I generate all the elements for each page, and then hide the ones that don't belong to page 1.  But I'm not sure how to do this without increasing the height of the page.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Well... what's your code for hiding the elements?  Are you using `visibility:hidden` or `display:none`?

Comment: Can we also see your JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply style="display:none" to the elements you want hidden.

The following code will hide "all" underlying pages within the div class='tab' element.

```
<div class='tab' style="display:none">
<div class='page'>...</div>
...
<div class='page'>...</div>
</div>
```

The following code will hide each page you specify style='display:none' to

```
<div class='tab'>
<div class='page' style="display:none">...</div> <!-- This page *only* will be hidden -->
...
<div class='page'>...</div> <!-- This page is still visible -->
</div>
```

Whenever you want an element to be visibile again just change your "display:none" to "display:block".

Answer (score 2):

start them with `style="display:none"` and then change them to `style="display:block"` as needed